# How to use checkbox as radio button for calculate total

Tags: javascript, html

I have below options, I want to use 1,2,3 options as radio button.

```
[checkbox] option 1 : $100 
[checkbox] option 2 : $200
[checkbox] option 3 : $300

[checkbox] Registration fee : $50 

Total = Option + Registration fee;
```

After selecting check box, value should be added into `total` and after unchecking, value should be deducte`from`total`. but the challenge is I want to use option 1,2 and 3 as radio buttons (only one option should be selected one time). But if I am using standard radio buttons for options then value is including in total on select but not deducting old options value from total if i select new option.

I used this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0;
    function fee(item) {
        if (item.checked) {
           total += parseInt(item.value);
        } else {
           total -= parseInt(item.value);
        }
        // alert(total);
        document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + "";
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="program1" value="100" onClick="fee(this);"/>
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="program2" value="200" onClick="fee(this);"/>
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="program3" value="300" onClick="fee(this);"/>
<input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" name="fee" value="50" onClick="fee(this);"/>
```

Comment: please update the question, showing the relevant code

Comment: option1=$('#Custom-ID').prop('checked').val(); registrationfee=$('#Custom-regist-ID').prop('checked').val();

Comment: For what purpose would you wish to make a checkbox behave like a radio-button? Why would such a purpose be worth the effort?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid... you can't have more than one element with the same `id` (i.e. `checkbox3`).  Also, you should always add a `radix` to `parseInt` so it's definitely parsed as base-10 (i.e. `parseInt(item.value,10);`)

Comment: you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/e07fjzg7/) ?

Comment: Because radio buttons does not have uncheck event, If i select option 1, then option2 and after that option 3 then the total is 100+200+300+reg fee. But i want if i select option 1, then option 2 total should be like this 100 - 100 +200 +reg fee = 250

Comment: Radios are mutually exclusive if you give them the same name. Hence the "radio"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need at least one of them.
Radios will uncheck if they have the same name:

```js
function calc() {
  var rads = document.getElementsByName("option"),
      reg = document.getElementById("reg"),
      total = document.getElementById("total"),  
      tot = 0;
  for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
    tot+=rads[i].checked?parseInt(rads[i].value,10):0;  
  }
  if (reg.checked) tot += parseInt(reg.value,10);
  total.value=tot;
    
 }

window.onload=function() {
  var rads = document.getElementsByName("option"),
       reg = document.getElementById("reg");
  for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
    rads[i].onclick=calc;
  }
  reg.onclick=calc;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option1" value="100" />100 
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option2" value="200" />200 
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option3" value="300" />300 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="reg" id="reg" value="50" />50<br/>
Total <input type="text" readonly id="total" /><br/>
```

---

The name and concept of "radio button" comes from the old car radios where pressing one button would make the other button reset:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is what i want

Comment: big plus for the photo

Comment: Using the DOM as a data storage is terrible practice. Also, you keep all the values twice, as strings and parse them back constantly. This code is straight out of 1999.

Comment: I agree. We are however talking about a one page registration for a fishing trip or scout outing. Not Booking.com

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
   

function fee(ev) {

 var total = 0;
    var item = ev.target;
    if (item.checked) {
        total += parseInt(item.value);
    } else {
        total -= parseInt(item.value);
    }
    // alert(total);
    document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total;
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('change', fee);
```

```html
<div id='Totalcost'>0000</div>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name='name' value="100">option1(100£)
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name='name' value="200">option2(200£)
    <br>
</form>
```

using `form` and `change` event the code is more concise

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to discuss about how your design is probably wrong.

But I like to introduce a solution that does not imply some javascript to disable all checkbox and only allow one to be selected.
By changing the style of a radio button to look like a checkbox, you can easily achieve what you are asking.

```css
form > input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
    appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="program" value="100" /> program1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="program" value="200" /> program2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="program" value="300" /> program3<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="50" /> fee
</form>
```

You SHOULD not use this and think of using some radio button. This is counter intuitive for users.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to uncheck one of the first three options.

Comment: I don't see OP specifying that it should be possible. Accepted answer seems to confirm.

Comment: I guess that's a matter of interpreting the question's description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a simple MVVM library for this, [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) is a rather simple example.
This way you don't have to use your DOM as a datastore and both your presentation and your logic are separated rather clearly.

```js
var v = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    checkboxes: [{
      name: 'first',
      value: 100,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 'second',
      value: 200,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 'third',
      value: 300,
      checked: false
    }],
    optional: {
      name: 'optional',
      value: 50,
      checked: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    foo: function() {
      var sum = this.checkboxes.reduce(function(sum, item) {
        return sum + (item.checked ? item.value : 0);
      }, 0);
      sum += this.optional.checked ? this.optional.value : 0;
      return sum;
    },
    bar: function(e) {
      if (e.targetVM.checked) {
        this.checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
          checkbox.checked = false;
        });
        e.targetVM.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li v-repeat="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{name}}" v-model="checked" v-on="click: bar" />
    <label for="checkbox_{{name}}">{{name}}: {{value}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="checkbox" v-model="optional.checked" id="optional_{{optional.name}}" />
<label for="optional_{{optional.name}}">{{optional.name}}</label>
<p>Total: <span v-text="foo()"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is pretty straight forward.

```
$(".total").html("$" + (parseInt($(this).val()) + 500));
```

Made a small fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sovsf5tw/).

Comment: Assuming OP even WANTS jQuery

Answer (score -2):

Try something like below, would require a lot of clean up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //set initial state.

    var fee= 50;
    $('#val1').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var returnVal = $('#val1').val();
            alert(returnVal);
            fee = parseInt(fee) + parseInt(returnVal); 
             alert(fee);
        } else {
        alert('unchecked');
        var returnVal = $('#val3').val();
            alert(returnVal);
        fee = parseInt(fee) - parseInt(returnVal); 
                     alert(fee);
        }

    });
     $('#val2').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var returnVal = $('#val2').val();
            alert(returnVal);
            fee = parseInt(fee) + parseInt(returnVal);
             alert(fee);
        } else {
        alert('unchecked');
        var returnVal = $('#val2').val();
            alert(returnVal);
        fee = parseInt(fee) - parseInt(returnVal);
         alert(fee); 
        }

    });
     $('#val3').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var returnVal = $('#val3').val();
            alert(returnVal);
            fee = parseInt(fee) + parseInt(returnVal);
             alert(fee);
        } else {
        alert('unchecked');
        var returnVal = $('#val3').val();
            alert(returnVal);
        fee = parseInt(fee) - parseInt(returnVal);
                     alert(fee); 
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I do not see any jQuery tagged. Also this is highly inefficient coding